# How can I make the count of frequency for each cluster separately - neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis

I am using this query to count the frequency of each "CPV" in cluster by using "total = 238" which is the number of distinct contract (Knowing that the total which is 238 here , will change from a cluster to another since it's the number of contracts distinct which changes from a cluster to another .

```
 MATCH (c1:Contrat1018)<-[r:HAS1018]-(p:CPV1018)-[x:HAS1018]->(c2:Contrat1018)
with distinct p.id as CPV , collect(p.id) AS Total , tofloat(count(p.id)) as Occurence , c1.clusterId as Cluster , c2.clusterId as Cluster2 , 3980 as total
where Cluster=Cluster2  
return Cluster , Cluster2 , CPV , Occurence  , TOFLOAT((Occurence / total )* 100) as frequence
order by Occurence desc
```

But the result that I am getting is the frequency of each CPV in all clusters . And what I really need to have as a result is the frequency of CPV in its cluster (in the cluster where he is working )

Here is the result that I am getting btw :

[image]

Comment: Your `WITH` clause looks very buggy, and is very likely not returning the results you expect. Try replacing everything after the `WITH` clause with `RETURN *` to see what that clause is returning. You should read up on how Cypher [aggregating functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/functions/aggregating/) (like `COLLECT` and `COUNT`) work, especially with `grouping keys`.

Comment: I am getting the same result even when I tried with RETURN *